# Unable to parse .msg files in for loop using python

Tags: python, outlook

I'm a newbie to Python programming. I need to automate copying about 450 "msg" files located within multiple sub-directories of a directory in Windows, to other directories based on the content within each "msg" file. I used following code:

```
from shutil import copy2
import win32com.client

# Function which returns dictionary with absolute filepaths, file names
def list_files(dir):
    r = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            r[os.path.join(root, name)]=name
    return r

allFiles = list_files(sourceDir)

# Parsing all emails
for filename in allFiles.items():
    if filename[1].endswith(".msg"):
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        try:
            email = outlook.OpenSharedItem(filename[0])
            emailContent = email.Subject + "\n" + email.Body
            print(emailContent)
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            print("File Not Found Error: " + str(e))
        finally:
            del email, outlook
```

Further down, I'm going to copy the files based on the content. But many of the filepaths for these emails are longer than 260 characters. So, I'm getting following error:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The URL was bad/not found:\r\n  "C:\\Users\\HPHP\\Documents\\...\\Data\\...\\IHI ...\\......". Cannot find this file. Verify the path and file name are correct.', None, 0, -2147024894), None)
```

If I rename the filename such that the absolute path length reduces below 260 characters, I'm not facing this error. However I need the filenames to be intact. I also tried bypassing the MAX_PATH limitation with following code, which isn't working in this case:

```
email = outlook.OpenSharedItem("\\\\?\\"+filename[0])
```

I tried another way, to change the current working directory for every iteration. Following is the code:

```
for filename in allFiles.items():
    if filename[1].endswith(".msg"):
        os.chdir(filename[0].replace(filename[1],""))
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        try:
            email = outlook.OpenSharedItem(filename[1])
            emailContent = email.Subject + "\n" + email.Body
            print(emailContent)
            ...
```

But, I'm facing following error:

```
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-c7dea54d9247> in <module>()
      5         try:
----> 6             email = outlook.OpenSharedItem(filename[1])
      7             emailContent = email.Subject + "\n" + email.Body

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in OpenSharedItem(self, Path)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', "We can't open '2013 Self Cert.msg'. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.\n\nTo check your permissions, right-click the file folder, then click Properties.", None, 0, -2147287038), None)
```

I'm not able to figure out the reason behind this error. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the MSG file to a temporary folder / file with the full path shorted than MAX_PATH.

Comment: 1. I need the original source directory hierarchy to replicate same structure within destination directory 2. Also, some of the file names are 260 characters in length

Comment: That is perfectly fine - process each MSG one at a time: you know the original file name and folder, the temporary MSG file is only for OpenSharedItem

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I'm able to copy all the files now with help of temporary folder. But, isn't there any other way to resolve above errors without needing to copy all the files to a temporary folder?

Comment: I don't see another way.